# Automake/autoconf won't work with lex/yacc

Tags: yacc, lex, autotools

I have the following problem iwth autoconf/automake: I have a couple of files generated written for flex/yacc. I added the following to configure.ac:

```
AC_PROG_YACC
AC_PROG_LEX
```

In the Makefile.am I wrote the following:

```
PARSER = parser.yy scanner.ll
AM_YFLAGS = -d

BUILT_SOURCES = parser.h

appname_SOURCES = analyze.cc (various other sources) \
  $(PARSER)
```

When I try to compile, every object is being created just fine, but the linking won't work:

```
g++ (various libs) -o appname appname-analyze.o  (various other objects)
appname-scanner.o 
(yet more objects) appname-scanner.o (and still more objects)
```

So automake includes the object *twice*, which screws up the build entirely and results in a lot of `multiple definition` errors. I would appreciate it if you could tell me what I am doing wrong or else show me an automake project where lex/yacc files are processed successfully.

Comment: D'Oh, I am such an idiot. The scanner.cc file was listed in the "appname_SOURCES" as well. Please close this... So embarassed